# Passing shell variable in hive script

Tags: shell, hive

I am running hive script using shell job, with passing some parameters.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db_${hivevar:myEnv}_travail.tble91_formation_eligible(
   ID_FORM_ELIG BIGINT,
   LIBELLE_COURT_FORM VARCHAR(50),
   DEBUT_VALID_FORM TIMESTAMP,
   FIN_VALID_FORM TIMESTAMP,
   CODE_BRANCHE_FORM VARCHAR(4),
   CODE_REGION_FORM VARCHAR(3),
   CODE_PUBLIC_FORM VARCHAR(1),
   ETAT_FORM VARCHAR(3),
   DATE_CREAT_FORM TIMESTAMP,
   ORIGINE_CREAT_FORM VARCHAR(20),
   DATE_MAJ_FORM TIMESTAMP,
   ORIGINE_MAJ_FORM VARCHAR(20),
   ID_LISTE_ELIG BIGINT,
   LIBELLE_FORMATION VARCHAR(255),
   CODE_DIPLOME INT,
   NUMERO_FORMATION VARCHAR(50),
   CODE_REFERENTIEL VARCHAR(50) COMMENT 'Code associé au type de référentiel (ex: RNCP, RS, ELU, CPF, ...)',
   CODE_RECONNAISSANCE VARCHAR(50)COMMENT 'Code de la reconnaissance (ex: RNCP1234, ELU134444, ...)',
   NIVEAU_CONTROLE_HABILITATION VARCHAR(50) COMMENT 'Niveau de contrôle d\'habilitation d\'une reconnaissance éligible CPF (informatif, bloquant, absent)'
   )
PARTITIONED BY TO_DATE('${hivevar:date_archive}')
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE  
LOCATION '/${hivevar:myEnv}/ep/traitement/le5/app_db/db_${hivevar:myEnv}_le5_travail.db/tble91_formation_eligible/';
```

The problem is about passing the **date_archive** as a partition column, it'is sourced from shell script as String, but I wanna convert it as a date column, so that I used **TO_DATE** function.
For information, date_archive has many date values like : 2022-02-03

But, this make a problem

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line
> 22:15 extraneous input 'TO_DATE' expecting ( near '(' in create table
> partition specification (state=42000,code=40000)

I tried :

```
BY (TO_DATE('${hivevar:date_archive}'))
BY (TO_DATE("${hivevar:date_archive}"))
BY (date_archive=TO_DATE("${hivevar:date_archive}"))
```

But always, I have errors, Any help, please ? Thank you

Comment: variable date_archive contains string date 2022-02-12?

Comment: @leftjoin, it has many date values like `2022-02-03`

Comment: It is not clear why are you trying to specify some values in partition spec. It should be just column name, not a function, not a value, not a list of values What ere you trying to achieve? Do you want to create a table only containing single date_archive  or some list of values? Please describe the use-case in details